# avoid re-reading pem file while creating openssl signatures

Tags: php, openssl

I am using a simple php code similar to the standard openssl_pkcs7_sign() example to sign many mails in a loop
http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php

The problem is this code is too I/O intensive. This reads the same certificates and calls the openssl functions in a loop.

Can I just read the certificate in memory and use for signing everytime

This is the relevant part of the script

```
<?php

$headers =  array( "From: Ram <ram@netcore.co.in>", "Subject" => "Signed mail");


/* All the recipients who will get the mail */
$users = array ( 'ram@netcore.co.in' , 'aa@netcore.co.in','bb@netcore.co.in');

foreach ($users as $rcpt){
  $headers['To'] = $rcpt;

openssl_pkcs7_sign($rcpt."infile.txt",
                   "outfile.txt","file://noPassPrivatePublicKey.pem",
                     array("file://noPassPrivatePublicKey.pem", ""),
                     $headers);

  /* Now make an smtp connection and send the mail */
  send_mail_to_smtp($from,$rcpt,"outfile.txt");
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sign the mail once and send it to all recipients. S/MIME signs the mail body, only. So setting the To: header afterwards won't invalid the signature.

Comment: No the actual mail is different for every recipient. These are individual account statements

Comment: Copy the certificate to a RAM disk (tmpfs).

Comment: Editing the question to make an initialy correct answer false and to justify voting the answer down is not the way to do. It is not my fault if you simplifyed your sample code to much.